# How to prevent other program from renaming other top_level windows caption

Tags: c#, acl, dacl

Context: I'm making a parental control application.

My App enumerates all top-level windows on the screen, and terminate other processes by window caption using

```
[EnumWindows(EnumWindowsDelegate lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam)],

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows)
```

SetWindowText(hwnd, WindowText, WindowText.Capacity).

But My App has a gaping security hole.

User can rename window caption using SetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd, String lpString). Then, I try to run cmd.exe as administrator, SetWindowText doesn't work for it.

I want to solve the problem at its root.

To prevent the unauthorized program from renaming other program's window caption,
How to grant write permission to all top-level windows or specific application in C#?

Comment: Why would such an app not run as a service?

Comment: You cant without writing a *dll injection library* hooking all calls to `SetWindowText` and proxying them to not work

Comment: I think the simplest way would be to run a thread monitoring your caption and restoring it if it changes

Comment: @GonenI yeah the is probable a windows message that propagates this as well